# Spring data JPA fetch data as stream of list of Object

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, java-stream

I've a Spring web application which uses Spring Data JPA to interact with DB. I've a table consisting millions of records and I want to export a CSV consisting huge amount of data, for this I considered using Stream.

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id=:id", nativeQuery = true)
public Stream<Object[]> getData(@Param("id") long id);
```

Executing query works fine and I get the data as stream but the problem occurs when I try to process the stream and I get `ClassCastException` i.e `BigInteger` cannot be cast to `Object`.
Can someone please suggest where I'm mistaking.

Comment: Don't you have a corresponding `Entity` for the repository? `Stream<Entity>` seems more plausible

Comment: No, I don't have an entity for  repository, also I'm joining multiple tables (query not shown  in question) so I'm expecting a resultset with multiple columns (which may vary), can't I have  a list of array of Object.

Comment: I would switch to JdbcTemplate for this task.

Comment: Wouldn't JDBC template will fetch and keep records in memory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got ClassCastException because it fetches only first field in select query which may be a numeric type.
I have the same problem and updating spring-boot-starter-parent to version 1.4.1.RELEASE make it works.
(spring-data-jpa: 1.10.3.RELEASE
hibernate-core: 5.0.11.Final)

Comment: Updating my spring IO to Athens RELEASE solved my problem.